# Why does Hashem wait ten years before He passes a decree?

Tags: time

The Yalkut Shimoni (Chapter 620) says, *"Hashem waits ten years before He passes a decree."*
Which is interesting, because it took [ten years to find and kill Osama bin Laden!](http://www.csmonitor.com/Commentary/Editorial-Board-Blog/2011/0502/Osama-bin-Laden-How-long-will-it-take-to-kill-his-ideology)

Why does Hashem wait *ten years* before He passes a decree?

Comment: Maybe to give them time to do Tshuvah?

Comment: How did the author(s) of that text know that?  Deduction from something in Tanach? A tradition passed down from ...somewhere?  Direct question and answer session with HaShem?  Just curious....